# $this->db->get() give empty results on valid query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have MYSQL query whenever it is executed in codeIgnitor as php , `$this->db->get()` gives empty results and when i run it directly in `phpmyadmin` , it gives results , why is that?

**phpmyadmin:**

[image: image query]

**CodeQuery:**

```
$this->db->select('courses.id AS courseId',false);
        $this->db->select('courses.Name AS courseName',false);
        $this->db->select("`assignments`.`Assignment#` AS assignmentName",false);
        $this->db->select('assignments.DueDate AS duedate',false);
        $this->db->select('assignments.DueTime AS duetime',false);
        $this->db->select('assignments.expiryDate AS expiryDate',false);
        $this->db->from('courses,user,assignments,course2teacher,follows');
        $this->db->where('user.id',$studentid);
        $this->db->where('follows.studentid=user.id');
        $this->db->where('follows.course2teacherid=course2teacher.id');
        $this->db->where('assignments.course2teacherid=course2teacher.id');
        $this->db->where('course2teacher.CourseId=courses.id');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        print_r($query); die();
```

**Output Code Query** is `NULL` ,  can anyone please explain what happened here , and how can i fix it ?

**Edit:**

My database structure is on : http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/

Just goto link , click `save/load` click `load` , type `isec` click `ok` , it is second day now just struggling with single query

Comment: deleted the answer below, anyway you get my point, solve your query first, when you're done with that don't forget to fetch after `->get()` https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Comment: the one query which is running in `phpmyadmin` in above screenshot , is the copy paste of query returned by `$this->db->last_query()` @Ghost

Comment: `query` is correct there is something wrong with `CI` i think

Comment: other queries are also running fine in `model` , just this one seems to keep mocking me..

Comment: a successful query results into a `CI_DB_mysqli_result Object` not `NULL` or `false`, then you can use the `->result()` method. can't help you more than anything than the one that's posted above, you already said the query generated by that active record above isthe same as the one you have at myadmin

Comment: if you are saying to try it like `$query = $this->db->get(); if($query){ return $query->result_array(); }` tried , didn't worked though , same NULL issue

Comment: i didn't say anything to do that, what i'm trying to say is clearly there is something wrong on how your active record fields are built. `->get()` isn't the issue. try to add `->where('course2teacher.CourseId=courses.id', null, false)` in there

Comment: No change , @Ghost , same NULL issue

Comment: Copy valid query from phpmyadmin and pass it to `$query = $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');` [method](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#regular-queries) just for testing purpose.

Comment: Can you try to run a much simpler query in your code for testing? Some simple select with one table and one condition? Suggesting this to verify that your code is running on the same DB+schema etc. Sometimes ppl forget that their code still runs on the test schema vs production etc.

Comment: @Tpojka tried that , give same NULL issue , @Galz , just tried this query `SELECT* from user` it works, but what good is this library for if it can't run complex queries ? and i am working on production environment

Comment: Is your query really necessary? Can you include in the questions your tables, what you want, and maybe we can make a simpler query ill help

Comment: what's the ouput of print_r($query); ?

Comment: @Mr.Z Prior to the query build: `$studentid = intval( $studentid );` This way; CI won't wrap integers. MySQL can be overly mis-forgiving.

Comment: @LorenzoMagno yes my query is important , i have mentioned how to access my db structure , @kool-Mind out of print_r($query) is `null` means nothing just `empty response` ,, @Mackiee , tried your solution didn't work though

Comment: @Galz , this is the simplest query i could think of , for my job , if you have a suggestion to improve kindly suggest

Comment: @Mr.Z - I don't mean a query that will work for this purpose. Just a simple query to see you are connected to the correct schema and that the 'pipes' are working

Comment: Use `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` to show what SQL queries is generated by Codeigniter.